# I have got a two CAML Queryies. How Could I done to see them in 3 montths from today

Tags: 2010, development, data-view-web-part, calendar

I have got a two CAML Queries. How Could i set them to see all object on ASP Calendar 3 months from today day? Here are the Queries:

```
 string DateOnlyQuery = "<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='{0}' /><Value Type='DateTime'>{1}</Value></Eq></Where>";
        string FullQuery = "<Where><And><Eq><FieldRef Name='{0}' /><Value Type='DateTime'>{1}</Value></Eq><Eq><FieldRef Name='Pracownik' /><Value Type='Text'>{2}</Value></Eq></And></Where>";
```

I want only Visible days

3 month from today > Dates on Calendar < Today date

Answer (score 1):

I think you need this -

```
<Where>
  <Geq>
     <FieldRef Name="Created" />
     <Value Type="DateTime">[Today-3Month(s)]</Value>
  </Geq>
</Where>
```

BTW why dont use some CAML query builder like [U2U](http://www.u2u.be/res/tools/camlquerybuilder.aspx) or any other tool, your task will be a lot easier if you use CAML query heavily

Comment: I Use but i don't cnow how to corelate all the Queries. Your Query and mine Query. With AND ? Sorry that I'm assking, but I'm beginer of CAML

Comment: That's why I asked you to use U2U, query construct should be - <Where><And><Geq>
     <FieldRef Name="Created" />
     <Value Type="DateTime">[Today-3Month(s)]</Value>
  </Geq>Your query part</And></Where> if you have more than one and condition the it should be <Where><And><And><Geq>
     <FieldRef Name="Created" />
     <Value Type="DateTime">[Today-3Month(s)]</Value>
  </Geq>Your first query</And>Your second query</And></Where> and so on, use CAML query builder things will be easier

Comment: I Use this Query and show me nothing:             `string DateOnlyQuery = "<Where><And><Eq><FieldRef Name='{0}' /><Value Type='DateTime'>{1}</Value></Eq><Geq><FieldRef Name='{0}' /><Value Type='DateTime'>[Today-8Day(s)]</Value></Geq></And></Where>";`

Comment: what is the value of {0} ? is it 'Created'? then what's the value of {1}? this query obviously wont work, one conflicts with another

Comment: I put this one Query as You told and don't see any eighter:`string DateOnlyQuery = "<Where><And><Geq> <FieldRef Name='Dzien' /> <Value Type='DateTime'>[Today-18Day(s)]</Value> </Geq><Eq><FieldRef Name='{0}' /><Value Type='DateTime'>{1}</Value></Eq></And></Where>";`

Comment: A String for this is: ` query1.Query = String.Format(DateOnlyQuery, "Dzien", dateISO);`

Comment: What is Dzien ? it it some custom date time field?

Comment: It's a date from the field from list caled "Dzien"

Comment: Name of list column is caled "Dzien"

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6545/discussion-between-diptarag-and-grzegorz-z)